# How to navigate page to ID in different languages?

Tags: html, wordpress, navigation

I have a multi language wordpress site. I am using the WPML plugin to have multiple languages.

The idea I want is as follows: I have a menu, inside the menu I have links. Some links go to ids to scroll to a specific sections in a page. When it comes to english (the main language of the site), this works fine example(example.com/#GoHere). But when it comes to other languages how can I implement the path? I tried this (example.com/ar/#GoHere). But the link does not work.

Is there a specific way to navigate with an ID for the other languages that is different to the main language path? For arabic the link path is example.com/ar/ But adding the id after it doesn't work like in the english pages.

Answer (score 0):

No it will read as a page if you append langauge code after url , If you wanted to do it , Then create subdomains which will read same code and db you just need to put condition in wp-config.php file like below:

```
$url_secure = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'on' ? "https" : "http") . "://";
$url = $url_secure.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
if(strpos($url, 'de.') !== false){
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://de.coodingdessign.com' );
define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://de.coodingdessign.com' );
}elseif(strpos($url, 'fr.') !== false){
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://fr.coodingdessign.com' );
define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://fr.coodingdessign.com' );
}else{
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'https://www.coodingdessign.com' );
define( 'WP_HOME', 'https://www.coodingdessign.com' );
}
```

Comment: How will this work could you please just explain a little further? I havent worked with php code before, do I place 'ar.' 'fr.' etc. for each if statement and language? And how will it help with what I am trying to achieve with the ID navigation?

Comment: First you need to create subdomain , you can use wm api to create subdomain as per your need (no of subdomain), according to your language id dynamically redirect for exacmple

$id.example.com

Comment: I tried something and it worked without the need of your suggestion, I very much appreciate your help and time! All I had to do was after the /ar/ was add the slug of the page in each language and then add the id.